# How to Determine the Installed ASP.NET Version of Host from a Web Page

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a site running in a Windows shared hosting environment. In their control panel for the shared hosting account I have it set to use ASP.NET version 3.0 but it doesn't say 3.5 SP1 specifically.

How can I view the installed version running on the server where my website is hosted in an asp.net page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks!

I just dropped <%=Environment.Version%> on a page and got 2.0.50727.3053

Answer (score 5):

@Jon Limjap: Unfortunately, this tells you the .NET CLR (runtime library) version, *not* the version of the .NET Framework.  These two version numbers are not always the same; in particular, the .NET Framework 3.0 and 3.5 both use the .NET CLR 2.0.  So the OP may indeed have only .NET 2.0 SP1, as the Environment.Version indicates, or he may also have the .NET 3.5 SP1 which he is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to throw an exception in Page Load, but don't catch it. At the bottom of the page, you'll see the version number.

Comment: I was getting an error anyhow, didn't think to actually read the text on the footer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The hint from Brian Boatright by putting the `<%=Environment.Version%>` on a page, and save it in DotNetVersion.aspx, upload it, at testing on the right URL, world great.

Sadly it was an too old version for me: 1.1.4322.2443